# why useRef dependency in useEffect run two times?

Tags: reactjs

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";


export default function App() {

  const refdata = useRef();

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("sam");
  },[refdata])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

output : I see two time sam in console.
I don't understand why console.log run twice.
please help me to understand this

Comment: It is not dependent on `useRef`. Any `useEffect` with a dependency(s) runs twice: first at the initial render, then when a dependency changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React 18, useEffect is getting called two times on mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount)